# Exporting a fbx file into Blender and adding texture turning black

Tags: unity

I am an absolute beginner in blender So i suspect I am missing something "obvious".  i create a simple cylinder in blender by

1) Mesh -> add cylinder

2) Add modifier -> solidify.

3) I have optionally gone into edit mode to recompute normals, recalculate outside/inside,  or performed UV unwrap.

After that i save as fbx file or just .blend file and import to unity. Thereafter, i want to add a shader/texture onto it by selecting an image and dropping it on top of the cylinder. It turns black. If i just create a red color material and drop that, it turns red.. but if i drop an image directly or by creating a shader  it turns black. For the life of me, i cannot figure out why that is happening.

I have seen some threads on baking texture in blender first, but for my purpose i need to do that in blender directly. I will appreciate any input on this.

my blender file: (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2215/)
[image: blender issue]

Comment: Plz add image on what u want to say and drop ur file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Here it is : [image][<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2215" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2215/)

Comment: It seems that this is not Blender related but Unity which is better asking on [forums for Unity](https://unity3d.com/community).

Comment: Did you UV unwrap the mesh?  Perhaps, without that, Unity doesn't know know to apply the image correctly?  Does Unite have any options on the image for its projection (cylindrical projection, e. g.)?

Comment: It seems i had to indeed UV unwrap the image before exporting. this video tutorial helped me out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfHcMTJWmA8               However, instead of a smoot inner (and outer) surface where i can texture the cylinder, i am getting multiple planes probably because its a combination of multiple triangles. I wonder if there is a way to texture entire cylinder inner (or outer) surface with 1 image only.

Comment: @RamanpreetSingh - you clearly need to watch some videos about texturing and unwrapping. This is crucial knowledge for creating game assets. There are tons out there on youtube and many, many blogs.